# HorizontalScrollView don't scroll left

Tags: android

I have a horizontalscrollview which inside it has a LinearLayout with TextView.

I am setting dynamically String that are longer every time to the TextView (like a calculator), But when the TextView gets wider, I can't scroll to the begining of it(to the left side in my handy), but only to the right side, which is just some empty space which I have no idea how it came.

In general, just can't scroll to one side(left) to see some of the TextView in the layout.

This is the xml of the scrollview:

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Hscrollbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="v"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Also in my activity, this is what I modified to the HorizontalScrollView:

```
     final HorizontalScrollView Hscrollbar = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Hscrollbar);
    Hscrollbar.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Hscrollbar.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    });
```

How can I make it scroll to the left side (which I want to see the whole TextView)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:foregroundGravity="right" from HorizontalScrollView.

Make LinearLayout width wrap_content and same for TextView.

Set TextView android:layout_gravity="right"

That might work.

Comment: No, that is not working. also setting to "left" not working.